# Firebase Ads is not showing

Tags: firebase, admob

Apps removed from Google play store due cause of **Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID**.

After submitting privacy policy apps is now available in play store but no ads is shown . I have used google firebase adMob network.  I have tested with with TEST_BANNER_ID, it's works good but live banner ad Unit ID does not work. If someone would help or give me suggestion how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Apps removed and real ads is  not  serving into apps**

**Causes and procedure to apply:**

When your apps has been removed from android play store for policy violation and you got a mail or notification . After while you have made changes to your apps in order to comply android apps policy and resubmitted the apps into play store , Google will check the apps changes . If it supports their privacy policy properly and you submit an application with proper justification , Then google will republished your apps and available again to the users .

I changed my apps accordingly to the google apps privacy policy and resubmitted the apps into play store. Google accepted my apps to re-publish and available to google play store. But advertising serving was not available from Admob . So I was worried and applied to re-enable ads serving . It has takes some days to re-serving ads into apps and admob informed me for the great news!